# Insert the name of file inside the file

Tags: bash

I have in a directory some *.csv files. I want to insert inside each file, its name.

The following code do it, but I also need to remove, delete the pattern .csv

```
for file in *.csv; do echo "$file,"$"$(cat -- "$file")" > "$file"; done
```

for example  if the name is London.csv and inside I have 10, 20, now I get

```
London.csv, 10, 20
```

I need to reduce it to,

```
London, 10, 20
```

With your help, I get it with this update

```
for file in *.csv; do echo ${file%.csv},"$"$(cat -- "$file")" > "$file"; done
```

Comment: `file="London.csv"; echo "${file%.*}"`

Comment: Thanks both       for file in *.csv; do echo ${file%.csv},"$"$(cat -- "$file")" > "$file"; done